# Best approach for manipulating multiple div elements? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, refactoring

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <ul class="top-attractions-prague">
            <li class="homepage-carousel-item">
            <div class="hci_thumb_abrupt" style="background-image:url(/86/28655.jpg)">
                <div class="hci_label_abrupt">
                    <div class="hci_label-container_abrupt">
                        <div class="hci_label-subcontainer_abrupt">
                            <p class="hci_label_txt_abrupt">You'll love food</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            <a class="hci_name_abrupt" href="/discover/country/it.html?">Prague</a>
         </li>

   <li class="homepage-carousel-item">
            <div class="hci_thumb_abrupt" style="background-image:url(/86/28655.jpg)">
                <div class="hci_label_abrupt">
                    <div class="hci_label-container_abrupt">
                        <div class="hci_label-subcontainer_abrupt">
                            <p class="hci_label_txt_abrupt">You'll love food</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            <a class="hci_name_abrupt" href="/discover/country/it.html?">Prague</a>
         </li>

   <li class="homepage-carousel-item">
            <div class="hci_thumb_abrupt" style="background-image:url(/86/28655.jpg)">
                <div class="hci_label_abrupt">
                    <div class="hci_label-container_abrupt">
                        <div class="hci_label-subcontainer_abrupt">
                            <p class="hci_label_txt_abrupt">You'll love food</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            <a class="hci_name_abrupt" href="/discover/country/it.html?">Prague</a>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

I want to add the class Active to the following parts:

```
".hci_thumb_abrupt"
".hci_label_abrupt"
".hci_label-container_abrupt"
".hci_label-subcontainer_abrupt"
".hci_label_txt_abrupt"
```

I wrote fast solution but i don't like repeating the loop:

```
$(function () {
var f = {
    $thumb: ".hci_thumb_abrupt",
    $label: ".hci_label_abrupt",
    $container: ".hci_label-container_abrupt",
    $subcontainer: ".hci_label-subcontainer_abrupt",
    $label_txt: ".hci_label_txt_abrupt"
};

$('.homepage-carousel-item').hover(
    function () {
        $.each(f, function (i, val) {
            $(val).addClass("active");
        });
    },
    function () {
        $.each(f, function (i, val) {
            $(val).removeClass("active");
        });
    }
);
```

});

Can someone provide me more elegant solution? I tried something like this:

```
    $(function (c, b, a) {
    c.fn.textLabel = function (d) {
        var w = {
            $item: ".homepage-carousel-item",
            $label: ".hci_thumb_abrupt"
        };
        var e = c.extend({}, w, d);
        return this.each(function () {
            c(this).bind({
                mouseover: function () {
                    c(this).addClass("active").find("*").addClass("active");
                    alert('bastead');
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    c(this).removeClass("active").find("*").removeClass("active");
                }
            })
        })
    }
});
```

But nothing happens with this second code, couldn't fully debug it..

NOTE THAT the ACTIVE class needs to apply to each `<li>` individually

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's start after comments

you have 2 selector ways to doing that

1st: to use

```
$(this).find('div').addClass('active');
```

so your code will be

```
$('.homepage-carousel-item').hover(
    function () {
            $(this).find('div').addClass("active");
    },
    function () {
            $(this).find('div').removeClass("active");
    }
);
});
```

this code will add Active class to all the divs inside the li you hove over it

2- to add class to each element you want to add class active to it

for example

```
<div class="to_add_active hci_label-subcontainer_abrupt">
```

Note: you can add to_add_active  to any element you want to add class Active to it

and use it like this

```
$(this).find('.to_add_active').addClass("active");
```

the next demo explain that

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/oqoqer56/2/)

Comment: this is nice, how about looping the main div to retrive all of the clasees? without calling them each by each, how can i do that?

Comment: I can see that, i am trying to apply active class on all of the divs without calling each one of them

Comment: @IlanHasanov you can use $('div').addClass('active');  and if you don't want some divs from them  use $('div').not('.divs_we_dont_want').addClass('active');

Comment: @IlanHasanov let me tell you something easier .. determine specific class for divs you need to add class active to it .. for example  for divs you need class="this_div_to_add_active"  and then use it like  $('.this_div_to_add_active').addClass('active');  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/oqoqer56/1/

Comment: the problem is i have multiple times this div repeating, and i need for each div repeat to apply active not all at once

Comment: @IlanHasanov updated answer .. just use the selector for divs inside each  li ... so you need to use $(this).find('div')   instead of  $('div')

Comment: What about the `<p>` with class "hci_label_txt_abrupt"